# Error in Shell Scripting Syntax Error bracket

Tags: shell, syntax

27: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

main.bash: line 27:`"5") echo -e "1)- Change the User name \n2)- Change the user Password \n3)- change the group"'

Comment: Is there actually a `"5")` at the beginning of line 27? If so, why is it there? It's not valid shell syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding spaces near `)`, it works most of the time for me.